# Negation of Limit Definition

Tags: analysis, logic

I know what the rules are for negation, so my problem isn't negating -- it's with the interpretation of the negation.
We can write $(x_n) \rightarrow x$ as
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n \ge n_0 \ |x_n-x| < \varepsilon$$
So its negation is:
$$\exists \varepsilon > 0 \ \forall n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists n \ge n_0 \ |x_n-x| \geq \varepsilon$$
In "plain English" I interpret the latter as:

> There exists a $\varepsilon$ with the property that for any chosen $n_0$, there is an $n$ such that the difference between $x_n$ and $x$ is greater than $\varepsilon$.

This doesn't make sense to me though -- because $|x_n-x| \geq \varepsilon$ seems to hold for only **a single** $n > n_0$. If $x$ is not a limit, shouldn't $x_n$ "stay away" from $x$ **for all** $n > n_0$?

Comment: No, $x_n$ doesn't need to stay away from $x$ **for all** $n > n_0$. Consider a simple example: $x_n = (-1)^n$. Then $x_n$ does not converge to $1$ or to $-1$ even though it equals both values infinitely many times.

Comment: @Bungo: That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Bungo what about $(1/2)^n$, if i choose $\varepsilon = 1/8$ and I'm testing convergence to $0$. At $n=1$, haven't I shown $(1/2)^n$ diverges?

Comment: @yoshi: What if $n_0=4$, though?

Comment: okay I think I see what's happening, I wasn't appreciating the role of $(\forall n_0)$ in the statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a number  $x$ not to be the limit of $x_n$ we want to have infinitely many terms of the sequence, stay out of some neighborhood of x.

That is exactly what you said in

$$\exists \varepsilon > 0 \ \forall n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists n \ge n_0 \ |x_n-x| \geq \varepsilon$$

For every $n_0$ there is an $n \ge n_0$ such that , 
$|x_n-x| \geq \varepsilon$